# Whats the differences between docker-compose down and docker-compose kill?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What is the differences between `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose kill`? Are they identical?

Answer (score 1):

`down` will wait for containers/services to exit "gracefully" while `kill` will send `SIGKILL` signal to stop services immediately.

From [docker-compose down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/):

> Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up.

From [docker-compose kill](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/kill/):

> Forces running containers to stop by sending a `SIGKILL` signal. Optionally the signal can be passed, for example:

```
docker-compose kill -s SIGINT
```